# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document

Tags: android, itextpdf

I have added the .jar files into my existing project as described in http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath .

When I try to run the emulator I end up with “java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document”

My .classpath file :

```
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itext-pdfa-5.3.3.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itext-xtra-5.3.3.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3-javadoc.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3-sources.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/itextpdf-5.3.3.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tmp;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          String FILE = "/home/ronline/Desktop/FirstPdf.pdf";
        try {
            Document document=new Document();
              PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
              document.open();
              document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using the latest ADT plugin version and have you added the jars inside the libs folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unknown reason getting the jars to Java Library through eclipse interfaces doesn't work. Manual copy / past into libs folder does the trick. Thx to  Parth Doshi suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should download jar from  [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/) and then try.