# NoclassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document error will opening a new itext document

Tags: android, eclipse, itext, simulation

I am working with Eclipse in an simulator Android device, I have the following simple code:

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "/example.pdf");
if(!file.exists())
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
Document document = new Document();
(…)
```

Since I do `Document document = new Document();`
I get the error:

> Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document

I have the itext.jar included like this:

```
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itext-pdfa-5.4.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itext-xtra-5.4.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itextpdf-5.4.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itext-pdfa-5.4.0-javadoc.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itext-pdfa-5.4.0-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itext-xtra-5.4.0-javadoc.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itext-xtra-5.4.0-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itextpdf-5.4.0-javadoc.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="assets/itextpdf-5.4.0-sources.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

And all of them in the path "assets".

Comment: Does this solution work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12770849/2086065

Comment: Are you using the latest ADT plugin version and have you added the jars inside the libs folder?

Answer (score 0):

By your error:

`Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document`

it look like you have imported the wrong `Document` class.

Try this import:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
```

Comment: Can we use `new org.w3c.dom.Document()`?

Comment: I'm using it in one of my projects, and don't encounter any problems, so yes you can use.

Comment: `org.w3c.dom.Document` is an interface. How can we do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question, here is how I use it: Document doc = parser.getDomElement(parameterMetaData);

Comment: The code in this question uses `Document document = new Document();`.

Comment: What I am trying to do is To create a PDF document with Itext, samethig like this: Document document = new Document();
           PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fop);
           document.open();
           document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
           document.add(new Paragraph("http://www.javatips.net/"));
           document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
           document.close();

Comment: `com.itextpdf.text.Document` and `org.w3c.dom.Document` are completely different. Thus, you cannot use them interchangeably.

Comment: I know I have to use com.itexpdf.text.Document, and It is the one i am using import com.itextpdf.text.Document;

Comment: then i guess that my answer is irrelevant, just ignore it. I'm not familiar with "com.itextpdf.text.Document", and just tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Android, it's better to use [the Android port](http://itextsupport.com/download/android.html).
This port is used in all our Android demos.
The differences with the pure Java iText version are:

1. No use of AWT, nio,... classes whatsoever,
2. Use of SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle to avoid know issues with BC on Android,
3. Removal of classes that don't work on Android anyway.

Note that a `NoClassDefFoundError` doesn't only occur when the class wasn't found. In your case: the class is there: just check the jar. Such an error can also be thrown when there's ambiguity. For instance: because you have two version of iText in your CLASSPATH. If I were you, I would remove all references to iText, then start anew with the Android port of iText. I'm pretty sure you have too much entries in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: I have tryed with dropitext and it is working     https://code.google.com/p/droidtext/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Droidtext isn't endorsed by its authors (me being one of them). It's not supported in any way.